# Win8 + Ubuntu 12.04: Grub loader menu is not shown any more

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I am sorry if this is a duplicate. Several months ago I managed to get Ubuntu 12.04 working on my laptop together with preinstalled Windows 8. It was quite a complicated procedure and this forum helped me a lot.

The case is that I have not used Ubuntu for several months and now I realized that I do not see the grub menu any more after reboot! I remember that I turned Fast Boot on after installing Ubuntu, but now it is off. Is something corrupted now?

Comment: I had a similar problem. My Notebook uses EFI and there are entries named HDD and Windows8 Loader. Check if Windows8 Loader has a higher priority than your HDD.

Comment: @Schlenderman: this is exactly what has happened, thanks a lot! Please post this as an answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

My Notebook uses EFI and there are entries named HDD and Windows8 Loader.

Check if Windows8 Loader has a higher priority than your HDD.